# Writing a regex in java. Using the string.split() method. I want it to stop splitting after the first occurrence of '('

Tags: java, regex

I have strings with this format:   "a,b, c,d" and this format:  "a(b,c,d)"
I want to split on ',' or ', ' but I want to terminate splitting when I encounter the '(' in the second format.
This is what I had before I started hacking.

```
String [] stringArray = string.split(", |,");
```

The array of the first format would contain:  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
The array of the second format would conaint 'a(b,c,d)'

Example:

```
String string1 = "ab,cd, de";
String string2 = "ab(de,ef);
String [] array1 = string1.split(...);
String [] array2 = string2.split(...);

array1 result: ["ab" "cd" "de"]
array2 result: ["ab(de,ef)"]
```

The number of characters between the commas are not limited.  I hope this is more clear.

Thanks.

Comment: so can you provide an example of a valid output, in other words, a valid `stringArray` after splitting "a,b, c,d(e,f,g)"

Comment: and should it restarts after `)`, I mean `a,b,c,d(e,f,g)h,i,l` shoudl split as a b c d (e,f,g) h i l ?

Comment: Thanks for asking.  I need to rephrase my question.  See the edit.

Comment: once splitting is terminated at (, it should not restart.

Comment: Your question still remains unclear, Add sample input & output.

Comment: @KuldeepJain I've updated the post in an attempt to make it more clear.

Comment: and "ab,cd(what,ever" should give "ab" "cd(what,ever", right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the parentheses are always properly balanced and they'll never be nested inside other parens, this will work:

```
String[] result = source.split(",\\s*(?![^()]*\\))");
```

If the lookahead finds a `)` without seeing a `(` first, it must be inside a pair of parens.  Given this string:

```
"ab,cd, de,ef(gh,ij), kl,mn"
```

...`result` will be:

```
["ab", "cd", "de", "ef(gh,ij)", "kl", "mn"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you could need is a negative lookbehind; according to the doc, Java regex are like (more or less) Perl regex; but variable length lookbehind is not implemented in Perl, so that `(?<!\(.*),\s*` won't work (it would match comma followed by any number of spaces or no space, and not preceded by a `(` followed by anything, i.e. would match comma only if not preceded by a `(`).

I believe the easiest thing is to split on the first `(` occurrence (you can avoid regex to do so) and treat the two resulting segments differently, splitting the first on `,` and adding to the final array the second (prepended with the maybe lost `(`).

**EDIT**

since "a(b,d)" should give "a(b,d)", you must append whatever comes after `(` (included) to the last splited string from the "first" segment. However, the concept is as written before.

Answer (score 0):

Use the indexOf() method.

Initially, check if a string has a "(".

```
   index = string.indexOf('(');  

   if(index ==-1)  // it means there is no '(' 
      {
        string.split(...);
      }
   else
      {
         subString = string.subString(0,index); // the part of the string before the '('

         // now do the following-
         // 1. proceed with split on substring

         // array1 = substring.split(...)

         // 2. Create a new array, insert the elements of array1 in it,
         // followed by the remaining part of the string

         // array2 = combine(array1, string.subString(index+1)); // <-- you will need to write this method   
      }
```